# Lanczos scale not working when scaleKey greater than some value

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimage, cifilter, lanczos

I have this code

```cc
CIImage * input_ciimage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.CGImage];
CIImage * output_ciimage =
[[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILanczosScaleTransform" keysAndValues:
                           kCIInputImageKey, input_ciimage,
                           kCIInputScaleKey, [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.72], // [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 800.0 / self.size.width],
                           nil] outputImage];
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef output_cgimage = [context createCGImage:output_ciimage 
    fromRect:[output_ciimage extent]];
UIImage *output_uiimage;
output_uiimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:output_cgimage 
    scale:1.0 orientation:self.imageOrientation];
CGImageRelease(output_cgimage);
return output_uiimage;
```

So, when scaleKey greater than some value then output_uiimage is black image.

In my case if value of key kCIInputScaleKey > @0.52 then result is black image. When i rotate image on 90 degree then i got the same result but value was 0.72 (not 0.52).

Whats wrong with library or mistake in my code?

I have iPhone 4, iOS 7.1.2, xCode 6.0 if needed.

Comment: I have this problem on iPad Air (ios 8.0.2 xcode 6) on big images. So CILanczosScaleTransform does black image with scale=0.5 (image size 4080x4080). On image with size 4096 this filter does black image every time. Same problems happen with other built-in and custom filters. I think, that CoreImage has still some problems with big images.

Comment: May be need to report bug to apple. I can't do it through my account.

Comment: Yes. I've reported bug to Apple.

Comment: Thanks. Please keep me informed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what Apple said:

> This scenario exposes a bug in Core Image. The bug occurs when rendering requires an intermediate buffer that has a dimension greater than the GPU texture limits (4096) AND the input image fits into these limits. This happens with any filter that is performing a convolution (blur, lanczos) on an input image that has width or height close to the GL texture limit.
>   Note: the render is succesful if the one of the dimensions of the input image is increased to 4097.
>
> Replacing CILanczosScaleTransform with CIAffineTransform (lower quality) or resizing the image with CG are possible workarounds for the provided sample code.

Comment: Hey George! We encountered a similar issue while working on our product. I'm sure your input could be highly valuable. Any chance you can take a quick look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57153640/metal-resize-video-buffer-before-passing-to-custom-kernel-filter/57163285?noredirect=1#comment100842018_57163285

Answer (score 0):

I've updated Bug report after request from Apple's engineers. They answer:

> We believe that the issue is with the Core Image Lanczos filter that
>   occurs at certain downsample scale factors. We hope to fix this issue
>   in the future.
>
> The filter should work well with downsample that are power of 2 (i.e.
>   1/2, 1/4, 1/8). So, we would recommend limiting your downsample to
>   these values and then using AffineTransform to scale up or down
>   further if required.
>
> We are now closing this bug report.