# Metal - Resize video buffer before passing to custom Kernel filter

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metal-performance-shaders, cikernel

Within our iOS app, we are using custom filters using Metal (CIKernel/CIColorKernel wrappers).

Let's assume we have a 4K video and a custom video composition with a 1080p output size, that applies an advanced filter on the video buffers.
Obviously, we don't need to filter the video in its original size, doing so we'll probably terminate the app with a memory warning (true story).

This is the video-filtering pipeline:

*Getting the buffer in 4K (as `CIImage`*) **-->**
*Apply filter on the `CIImage`* **-->**
*the filter applies the `CIKernel` `Metal` filter function on the `CIImage`*-->
*Return the filtered `CIImage` to the composition*

The only two places I can think of applying the resize is before we send it into the filter process or within the `Metal` function.

```
public class VHSFilter: CIFilter {

    public override var outputImage: CIImage? {
        // InputImage size is 4K
        guard let inputImage = self.inputImage else { return nil }

        // Manipulate the image here

        let roiCallback: CIKernelROICallback = { _, rect -> CGRect in
            return inputImage.extent
        }


        // Or inside the Kernel Metal function
        let outputImage = self.kernel.apply(extent: inputExtent,
                                            roiCallback: roiCallback,
                                            arguments: [inputImage])

        return outputImage

    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm not the first one to encounter this issue

**What does one do when the incoming video-buffer are too large (memory-wise) to filter, and they need to resize on-the-fly efficiently? Without re-encoding the video before?**

Comment: Have you tried inserting a scaling transform such as a `CILanczosScaleTransform` in the chain before your custom filter/kernel?

Comment: Hey @warrenm , thank you for replying! I haven't used it, but I did use `CIImage` `transformed(by:)` function to reduce the image size (which doesn't appear to change the RAM usage). Does is the same as `CILanczosScaleTransform` or Lancz doing something different?

Comment: I'm not sure of the implementation details, but it might be the case that the transformed image just holds the original image data and the transform, in order to avoid an expensive allocation. You might have to force it by using a filter such as Lanczos that (probably) actually does the resampling as an explicit step.

Comment: @warrenm I'll give it a try tomorrow. Is Lanczos base on Metal? In case (hopefully) it's actually dowing resampling, should it be efficient enough to do it per-frame without drop frames? Although in theory, if it's resampling the gain of filtering resampled buffer should be higher than the resample process itself in total(maybe?)

Comment: I assume it will use Metal when run with a Metal context. Lanczos is a relatively expensive and high-quality filter; I don't know how performant it will be going from 4K to 1K on recent iPhone hardware. But yes, the theory is that by giving the rest of the pipeline far fewer pixels to deal with, the cost of downsampling will be offset by the reduced cost of running subsequent filters. Hard to say without testing.

Comment: Hey @warrenm. Me & Frank going to tackle this to find out what's the most efficient method (altho, as for now there is no working method). I've created a GitHub Repo and set up the pipeline with a 4K video. If you are interested, I can add you as a collaborator so you could also take a look. If you are interested, send over your GitHub user name. Either way, I'll make a blog post later this week (if we'll solve it haha), and update you. Have a great day!

Comment: Hey @RoiMulia were you ever able to fix this? I am facing similar issue. Interestingly if I use built in CIFilters, app doesn't crash (memory usage is pretty stable). Though even if I use a custom passthrough filter, memory usage keeps on increasing till the app crashes. Somehow Custom filters are treated differently :( . Have done regular stuff like changing render size and using CILanczosScaleTransform to reduce the input image size to custom filter. Would really appreciate if you could point me to right direction.

Comment: @Amit I have the same problem here. Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As warrenm says, you could use a `CILanczosScaleTransform` filter to downsample the video frames before processing. However, this would still cause AVFoundation to allocate buffers in full resolution.

I assume you use a `AVMutableVideoComposition` to do the filtering? In this case you can just set the `renderSize` of the composition to the target size. From the docs:

> The size at which the video composition should render.

This will tell AVFoundation to resample the frames (efficiently, fast) before handing them to your filter pipeline.

Comment: Hey Frank, thank you again. I promise this is the last issue I'm posting about Metal haha. I did change the `renderSize` property, but the source `CIImage` `extent` is still and their original size (4K, `(0.0, 0.0, 2160.0, 3840.0)`). The visual output that I see is what I change the `renderSize` to, but the processed frames seem not to their size. Is it meant to be that way?

Comment: You are right! The `renderSize` property doesn't affect the `sourceImage`s of the `AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest`, it only sets the `renderSize` of the request and it seems you are to use that when doing your processing. So I guess the  `CILanczosScaleTransform` is the best option then. @warrenm Do you want to post that as answer?

Comment: Actually I haven't found Lanczos filter improving anything. Something's wierd about using Metal Kernel animations, it's consuming so much memory, even if I'm changing our VHS filter to do almost a void function (returning the same src buffer without manipulation). I'd love to share this with you. Is it possible (totally understandable if not) if you'll provide us a short *paid* consultant for about an hour (via Skype or something), so we can review our code and find the pitfalls?

Comment: This is with SpriteKit + CoreImage but you might be interested. I would suggest that you simply resize with Metal to reduce the video size before attempting any filters. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54431826/skeffectnode-combined-with-cifilter-runs-out-of-memory

Comment: Hey @MoDJ, thank you for replying. It one of the methods we are going to try today. When processing a single video it's usually okay. The issues start when you use `AVVideoComposition` to combine multiple videos playing at the same time. We'll try to tackle this in the upcoming days. If you are interested - send over your GitHub user name and I'll add you as a collaborator for our tryouts git. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hi Roi, My github username is mdejong, I would be interested in seeing what you come up with.